# Is there any solution for this system of equations for value of $~\lambda =8~$?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Look at the question in the image.

What I believe is that " we have no solution if $~\lambda =8~$" reason being : if $~\lambda =8~$, then $1{st}$ and ^$3^{rd}$ row are same and if we perform the operation $R_3\to R_3-R_1$ , we get  $~0~~ 0~~ 0~$ .

Then no solution. Am I correct ?

Comment: If $\lambda=8$, look at the right-hand-side of the equations. The 1st and 3rd line have a different right-hand-side. But yes, then there is no solution. And indeed, the determinant of the matrix is zero for $\lambda=8$.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the given linear system as $A~X=b$

$\implies \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 4 \\
2 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & \lambda -4 
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix} 
x \\
y \\
z 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
6  \\
4 \\
\lambda 
\end{pmatrix}$

Augmented matrix

$(A|b)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 
  1 & 2 & 4 & 6\\
  2 & 1 & 2 & 4 \\
  1 & 2 & \lambda -4 & \lambda
\end{array}\right) \underset{\overset{r_2-2r_1}{\longrightarrow}}{\overset{r_2-r_1}{\longrightarrow}} \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 
  1 & 2 & 4 & 6\\
  0 & -3 & -6 & -8 \\
  0 & 0 & \lambda -8 & \lambda-6
\end{array}\right)$

**Case I:** $~~ $If $~\lambda=6,~$ then there are $~3~$ equations with $~3~$ number of unknowns, so the linear system has unique solution.

**Case II:** $~~$If $~\lambda=8,~$ then we have $~0~x+0~y+0~z=2~$, which is impossible, so the linear system has no solution.

**Case III:** $~~$ If $~\lambda\neq 6,~$

*Sub case I:* $~~$ Let $~\lambda\neq 8,~$ then there are $~3~$ equations with $~3~$ number of unknowns, so the linear system has unique solutions.

*Sub case II:* $~~$ Let $~\lambda = 8,~$ then we have $~0~x+0~y+0~z=2~$, which is impossible, so the linear system has no solution.

**Case IV:** $~~$ If $~\lambda\neq 8,~$

*Sub case I:* $~~$ Let $~\lambda\neq 6,~$ then there are $~3~$ equations with $~3~$ number of unknowns, so the linear system has unique solutions.

*Sub case II:* $~~$ Let $~\lambda = 6,~$ then there are $~3~$ equations with $~3~$ number of unknowns, so the linear system has unique solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check R3-R1 on the constant vector, which gives $(6,4,\color{red}{2})$.  So the R3-R1 equation reads $0x+0y+0z=\color{red}{2}$ and that clearly means no solution.

To get infinitely many solutions you would have needed another $0$ to augment the row of zeroes in the coefficient matrix, and also check the consistency of the remaining two rows.